# Google app script on how to create a pdf from the data received from the spreadsheet and send the pdf file via email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

Template in the form of Google Docs
Data in the form of Google Sheets

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas :

- use [SpreadsheetApp class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) to read your sheet and get your data
- use [DocumentApp class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app) to copy your template, then read your template copy (via Document.getBody() and Body.getText())
- use javascript [Prototype.string.replaceAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) to replace template with data
- use [Document.getAs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#getascontenttype) to transform into PDF
- use [GmailApp class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app) to send the email

Tip for your next question : be a little more specific.